# How to implement a lossless URL shortening

Tags: c, http, url-shortener

First, a bit of context:

I'm trying to implement a URL shortening on my own server (in C, if that matters). The aim is to avoid long URLs while being able to restore a context from a shortened URL.

Currently I have a implementation that creates a **session on the server**, identified by a certain ID. This works, but consumes memory on the server (and is not desired since it's an embedded server with limited resources and the main purpose of the device isn't providing web pages but doing other cool stuff).

Another option would be to use **cookies** or [**HTML5 webstorage**](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) to store the session information in the client.

But what I'm searching for is the possibility to store the shortened URL parameters in **one parameter** that I attach to the URL and be able to re-construct the original parameters from that one.

First thought was to use a [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoding to put all the parameters into one, but this produces an even larger URL.

Currently, I'm thinking of compressing the URL parameters (using some compression algorithm like *zip*, *bz2*, ...), do the Base64-encoding on that compressed binary blob and use that information as context. When I get the parameter, I could do a Base64-decoding, de-compress the result and have hands on the original URL.

**The question is:** is there any other possibility that I'm overlooking that I could use to lossless compress a large list of URL parameters *into a single smaller one*?

---

**Update:**
After the comments from *home*, I realized that I overlooked that compressing itself adds some overhead to the compressed data making the compressed data even larger than the original data because of the overhead that for example [zipping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) adds to the content.
So (as *home* states in his comments), I'm starting to think that compressing the whole list of URL parameters is only really useful if the parameters are beyond a certain length because otherwise, I could end up having an even larger URL than before.

Comment: I guess there is only one way of doing this - using a lookup table as you already did with the session. You don't have external storage available on your embedded server (db, file system)? In the end you must store the information somewhere, by making it 'smaller' you will always loose information.

Comment: @home: if I use a packing-algorithm (zip, bz2), I won't loose information, right?

Comment: Yeah, but it may blow up the length of your URL. Only for very long URLs it'll reduce the length. What I meant with 'smaller' is removing information from the URL. I tried the same some weeks ago - zip > base64 encoding, did not work for me :-)

Comment: BTW: Now my plan is to shorten URLs only if they are beyond a certain length... the disadvantage is those URLs are not user friendly.

Comment: @home: thanks for the hint with the certain length. Updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always roll your own compression. If you simply apply some [huffman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) coding, the result will always be smaller (but then base64 encoding it, it'll grow a bit, so the net effect may perhaps not be optimal).

I'm using a custom compression strategy on an embedded project I work with where I first use a [lzjb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZJB) (a lempel ziv derivate, follow link for source code, really tight implementation (from open solaris)) followed by huffman coding the compressed result.

The lzjb algorithm doesn't perform too well on very short inputs, though (~16 bytes, in which case I leave it uncompressed).